# Finding the numbers that are palindromic in both base 2 and 10 and summing them up

Tags: c, sum

I need to find the sum of all numbers that are less or equal with my input number (it requires them to be palindromic in both radix 10 and 2). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pal10(int n) {
    int reverse, x;
    x = n;
    while (n != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10 + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    if (reverse == x)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int length(int n) {
    int l = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n = n / 2;
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}

int binarypal(int n) {
    int v[length(n)], i = 0, j = length(n);
    while (n != 0) {
        v[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= length(n); i++) {
        if (v[i] == v[j]) {
            j--;
        } else {
            break;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    long s = 0;
    int n;

    printf("Input your number \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n != 0) {
        if (binarypal(n) == 1 && pal10(n) == 1)
            s = s + n;
        n--;
    }
    printf("Your sum is %ld", s);
    return 0;
}
```

It always returns 0. My guess is I've done something wrong in the `binarypal` function. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

- function `pal10()` fails because `reverse` is not initialized.
- function `binarypal()` is too complicated, you should use the same method as `pal10()`.
- you should avoid comparing boolean function return values with `1`, the convention in C is to return `0` for false and non zero for true.
- you should avoid using `l` for a variable name as it looks very similar to `1` on most constant width fonts. As a matter of fact, it is the same glyph for the original *Courier* typewriter font.

Here is a simplified and corrected version with a multi-base function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ispal(int n, int base) {
    int reverse = 0, x = n;

    while (n > 0) {
        reverse = reverse * base + n % base;
        n = n / base;
    }
    return reverse == x;
}

int main(void) {
    long s = 0;
    int n = 0;

    printf("Input your number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n > 0) {
        if (ispal(n, 10) && ispal(n, 2))
            s += n;
        n--;
    }
    printf("Your sum is %ld\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will keep in mind your advice.I'm planning on learning pointers in the next 2-3 days. Any video tutorial or tutorial in general that would help me out?( I know there are tons of people that have tutorials,but I'd like to ask for your opinion)

Comment: @AlexBalauca: I do not have a favorite and have not looked for one in a long time.  Your best bet to understand pointers is to get help from a friend who understands them.  In short, a pointer is a simple object that contains the memory address of another object.  You can change its value to make it point to a different object.  Think of an address book: it is an array of pointers to houses: each page of the address book is a pointer to an actual house (or none if it is blank). You can change the address by writing a new one on the page.  Some of these addresses might also be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

in the function pal10 the variable reverse is not initialized.

```
int pal10(int n)
{
    int reverse,x;
        ^^^^^^^
    x=n;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        reverse=reverse*10+n%10;
        n=n/10;
    }
    if(reverse==x)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

In the function `binarypal` this loop is incorrect because the valid range of indices of an array with `length( n )` elements is `[0, length( n ) - 1 ]`

```
for(i=0;i<=length(n);i++)
{
    if(v[i]==v[j])
    {
        j--;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And as **@BLUEPIXY** pointed out you shall remove the break statement from this else

```
    else
    {
        break;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Works alright now that I've changed it. Also just to make sure I understand, I should remove "break;" because if I use return 0 I break the loop anyway,right?